# Custom pen mode in delphi

Tags: delphi

Does anyone know how it is possible to create a new pen mode so that I can use it in this way:
`shape1.pen.mode:=pmCustom;`
Then I'm gonna define what color each pixel must have. For example, I'd create a pen mode that paints blue when behind the specified pixel is a light colored one; and paints white when the behind pixel is dark.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems unlikely. This maps directly onto GDI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The VCL property `TPen.Mode` maps onto the GDI function [`SetROP2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145088%28VS.85%29.aspx). This has no option for what you describe and so I believe that what you ask is not possible.

To achieve the sort of effect you are looking for is likely going to require some hand-crafting.